# Ruby on Rails & Heroku - "Too many connections for role"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am running a rails app on Heroku hobby-basic plan and for some reason I keep getting the infamous "Too many connections for role " error whenever I try to connect to the production database. This means automated backups keeps failing and rake tasks won't run because they are denied connection.

Every time I run `heroku pg:info` it says 20/20 connections. If I run `heroku pg:killall` then all connections are killed and it says 0/20 until I restart all dynos and it instantly goes back to 20/20.

I managed to run `heroku pg:psql` by killing all connections and restarting the server to trigger the connection leak. Running `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity` reveals many idle "SELECT 1" queries but not where they come from. Here is a typical row limited to application_name, client_addr, waiting, state and query:

`bin/rails | 10.14.19.163 | f | idle | SELECT 1`

Now imagine that x20, all started milliseconds between each other. The staging-app does not show these symptoms and is constantly at around 1/20 connections.

This all started after a fairly large but ordinary deploy from staging to production (basically just adding some new views, models, controllers, precompiled assets, etc).

Any help debugging this mess would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

database.yml

`default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>`

`heroku ps` says the following:

`=== web (Hobby): bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV (1)
web.1: up 2018/08/11 23:10:04 +0200 (~ 13h ago)`

Comment: What is in your `database.yml` and what do you see when you run `heroku ps`?

Comment: Hmmm, nothing unusual there. I'm not too familiar with Thin, so I'm sort of at a loss. I'd try switching to Puma as documented [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server).

Comment: I tried switching to Puma, problem persists.

Comment: Let's see... `heroku ps` shows you're running a single web dyno and nothing else. `database.yml` shows a connection pool of 5. All this means I'd expect to see a MAX of 5 connections to Postgres, unless you configured Puma to run multiple workers (which I doubt you did). My only other suspicion (while unlikely) is another app connecting to the same DB. `heroku pg:credentials:rotate` might be worth a shot.

Comment: Rotated credentials, didn't work either. This has to mean the app itself is generating these `SELECT 1` requests? Which is weird as hell, since `SELECT 1` is basically just a ping.

Comment: How about `SELECT application_name from pg_stat_activity WHERE datname IS NOT NULL ORDER BY application_name`. That'll indicate where the `SELECT 1` are coming from.

Comment: It doesn't give more information than `bin/rails` unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This could be cause by a few things. One of them could be if you're using a concurrent web server like Puma, it could be getting that many connections when deployed in production.

A way to debug this is starting your application in production mode:

`rails server -e production`

And in your database check the number of connections

`select * from pg_stat_activity`

And check which process is taking connections. If the problem remains considering using a connection pool [PgBouncer](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#limit-connections-with-pgbouncer)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried pulling the production database locally and running the server in production mode but I was not able to replicate the problem.I've read about PgBouncer but I feel this is really a last resort kind of solution since there obviously is some kind of connection leak happening.

Comment: Connect to the heroku postgres and run the same query there `select * from pg_stat_activity` that should give you at least which process is consuming connections

Comment: I tried that and all I found was a bunch of idle `SELECT 1` queries (see my question).

Comment: [Here's a nice article](https://www.atemon.com/blog/pgerror-fatal-too-many-connections-for-role-xxxxxxx/) you might have encountered already. Without many details on how database hungry is your app or which web server you're using it's a bit hard to debug. Hope it helps

Comment: The app is running on a Thin web server v1.7.2 and it's not very database hungry at all, at most around a dozen concurrent users. As stated in the original post, none of these symptoms occured before the last deploy. The first time I got the error was immediately after deployment when I tried running migrations.

The article raised a lot of valueble point, thank you for sharing.

Comment: I guess you haven't change anything in your `production.rb` or any Heroku's environment variable?

Comment: No, nothing is changed in `production.rb` or in Heroku's vars.